# Store - Bug, updating modifier name disables field_name:price?

Tags: expresso-store

I have some products setup in Store with a variation modifier.

In the options column if I edit option values it seems to stop prices from displaying in the templates, unless I save the entry twice, and then it displays!

So in my store entry I have a product with these values in the options fields:

Basic
Complete: basic product + addon

And on my shop index template i am using this tag (which i'm assuming displays the based price without modifiers):
{cf_shop_product_details:price_inc_tax}

When i save the entry, no price shows up in the template.  If i resave the entry (making no changes), the base price then shows!

EE 2.4.0
Store 1.6.3

edit: I've found that if i edit the modifiers, i have to click on the stock field (the names then update there too) in order to make the tag display correctly.  Opening the entry again have the same effect of making the stock field update.

Comment: Are you sure on first save it isn't actually being saved? If you navigate away from that publish page and then go back in has the modification you made disappeared? Also, check the very top of the publish page to ensure no message has appeared in the message bar (you may just see a tab on the right side).

Comment: Also, can you provide an example of the non alphanumeric characters that you are adding in the options column?

Comment: example of the characters are  
: + (eg the full option is "Complete: basic product + addon")

They are being saved first time around. I am navigating away from the publish page and back again.

Comment: So the saved revisions just don't display on the front-end after first save?

Comment: the {cf_shop_product_details:price_inc_tax} doesn't display unless I save the entry twice.  
If i display the modifiers separately using {modifiers}/{modifier_options} it actually shows the special characters on first save.

Comment: I've noticed something.  When editing a modifier the stock field names don't change on the fly. If i click on a stock field the name updates and then the save works.  So previously that stock field wasn't getting updated until the publish page reloaded?

So if i edit a modifier, then click on the corresponding stock/sku field below all the names update and everything is ok.  If i don't click on the stock field these details don't seem to update causing the problems on the front end...

Comment: disregard what i said about non alpha characters, it seems this isn't the case and happens with any kind of modification of the modifier names.

Comment: Can you post a Pastie/gist of your template code?

Comment: @JustinLong
http://pastie.org/7941391  

To recreate the issue:  
1) Add a price to the "product details" tab.  
2) In the product modifiers tab, create a "variation" and in the options column add a couple modifiers giving them an "option" name etc.
3) in the stock field add your SKUs etc.
4) save the entry and check template, it should be ok.
5) Open previous entry and change one of the option names for your modifiers, don't click on the stock field and save the entry.
6) {field:price_inc_tax} doesn't display.
7) repeat step 5 but this time click on the stock field (triggers an ACT?), works.